# How to extract the public key from .cer file using node.js?

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptography, cryptojs

I have a .cer file containing the public key of an entity, to make a request to the entity I need to encrypt the session key using this public key(RSA algorithm). How do I get the public key from the .cer file to use here?

```
const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer)
```

Comment: see [crypto.createPublicKey](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createpublickey_key). Note this sentence: *If the format is 'pem', the 'key' may also be an X.509 certificate.*

Answer (score 0):

CER file is used to store X.509 certificate. The file contains information about the certificate owner and public key. A CER file can be in binary (ASN.1 DER) or encoded with Base-64

The public key is  going to be in a block (after decoding if it was base64)

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCsM+whXrxmbCkPfkwY2EehYpIp
*blah blah blah blah*
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Open the file with the `fs` module and decode is if it  is already encoded with base64. Then you can split the entire string by `-----` which will give you an array whose 2nd element is going to be the key.

Comment: No, the public key is not so easily extracted from an X.509 certificate, you are leaving out essentially all the steps needed to accomplish it.